# python boto3 dynamodb query function dynamic arguments

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Python boto3 library dynamodb.query method.
how do we pass dynamic arguments

```
client = boto3.resource("dynamodb")

params = {
    "Limit": 10,
    "ExpressionAttributeNames":{"#pk":"pk"},
    "ExpressionAttributeValues":{":pk":"value"},
    "KeyConditionExpression":"#pk=:pk",
    "ScanIndexForward": False
}
res = client.query(params)
```

It responds with error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with ** to set the parameters correctly:

```
res = client.query(**params)
```